# multiple classes for one element in Bootstrap4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Can I make all Bootstrap classes in the main DIV instead of assigning them to each DIV or INPUT, for instance, this is the normal Bootstrap navbar, I'm assuming if possible to collect all the classes in the DIV, I've heard about it but didn't find it anywhere. Thanks

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contactus.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>            
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're asking specifically about bootstrap, i.e., whether or not those two classes can be used together or if you're just asking in general?

You can apply as many classes to an element as you want, just separate class names with space

```
<div class="active dropdown-toggle custom-class"></div>
```

but only a single id:

```
<div id = "btn1 btn">  <!-- this is wrong --> </div>
```

Comment: I mean collecting all the classes from <ul> and <li> and put them in the main <div>. so the DIV could be like this `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-item nav-link navbar-nav mr-auto">`

Comment: That wouldn't work. These classes are built in such a way where they only target the element they are applied to and not through inheritance, and some of the styling functionality such as active link styling depends on this parent child structure.